# Ayuda a mejorar este código QT y C++

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy intentando hacer este código más ordenado y eficiente. Lo que quiero es meter esta linea en un qtreewidget y llamar a la variable:

```
ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]
```

Pero lo hago como he creado una aplicación de chat con diferentes contactos y hago este cambio me pone el siguiente mensaje:

> ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file
>   C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_static\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 545

Esto es porque esta intentando acceder cuando los datos no están disponibles creo.

Codigo:

```
void MainWindow::cambioRoster(QString barejid, QString resource)
{
    if(cliente.rosterManager().isRosterReceived() == true)
    {
        QXmppPresence::Type a = cliente.rosterManager().getPresence(barejid,resource).type();
        QIcon online;
        online.addFile(":/icons/user-online.png");
        if(ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly).size() == 0)
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
            item->setText(0,barejid);
            ui->arbolConectados->addTopLevelItem(item);
        }
        if(a == QXmppPresence::Available)
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
            item->setText(0,resource);
            item->setIcon(0,online);
            ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->addChild(item);
        }
        if(a == QXmppPresence::Unavailable)
        {
            int i=0;
            while(i<ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->childCount() && ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->child(i)->text(0) != resource) //busqueda lineal
            {
                i++;
            }
            ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->takeChild(i);
            if(ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->childCount() == 0)
            {
                online.addFile(":/icons/user-offline.png");
            }
        }
        ui->arbolConectados->findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly)[0]->setIcon(0,online);
    }
}
```

Si hace falta mas detalles puedo aportar más.

Comment: La lista está vacía. Otra no hay. Bien `barejid` tiene algún espacio extra en los extremos (prueba a pasarle un `trim` a la cadena por si acaso), la búsqueda falla por cualquier otro motivo, o porque no estás añadiendo los ítems correctamente.

Comment: como puedo hacer lo del trim? lo intente pero no me deja pasarle argumentos

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#trimmed es un método que devuelve una copia del string, pero con los espacios quitados de los extremos: `barejid.trimmed()`, es decir, que no modifica al string original, sino que devuelve uno nuevo modificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estoy intentando hacer este código más ordenado y eficiente.

Hay ciertas reglas generales que puedes seguir para conseguir un código más ordenado; en cuanto a la eficiencia dependerá de otros factores.

Sin ver el código completo es difícil tener en cuenta algunas de las reglas, pero para empezar podrías considerar el [Principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) tanto en clases como en funciones (el libro "[*Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship* [image]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)" hace especial hincapié en las funciones).

Otra guía que puede ayudarte para hacer el código más legible es documentar, documenta mucho, ["*Documenta como si la persona que fuese a mantener tu código fuese un psicópata violento que sabe dónde vives*"](http://www.softwarequotes.com/showquotes.aspx?id=617), no sólo por el bien de tus compañeros de equipo si no por el tuyo propio: el código que hoy te puede parecer claro y auto-explicativo mañana te puede parecer arcano e indescifrable... así que pon muchos comentarios: pero comentarios útiles. Puedes leer más acerca de la utilidad de los comentarios como complemento al código en este excelente [artículo de Coding Horror [image]](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/).

Centrándonos en medidas más concretas, no tengas miedo en usar variables temporales para guardar objetos intermedios, esto además de ayudarte a cumplir [el principio DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) puede también ayudarte a evitar cálculos de más, como indirecciones.

Así pues, almacenando en variables temporales `ui->arbolConectados`, `cliente.rosterManager()`, `.rosterManager()` y `ui->arbolConectados->findItems(...)[0]` te ahorras varias indirecciones (`->`) accesos a función `.rosterManager()`, accesos a función `->findItems` y accesos al operador corchetes además de hacer bastante más legible el código:

```
void MainWindow::cambioRoster(QString barejid, QString resource)
{
    auto &rosterManager = cliente.rosterManager();

    if(rosterManager.isRosterReceived() == true)
    {
        auto &arbolConectados = *ui->arbolConectados;
        auto barejidItems = arbolConectados.findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly);

        if(barejidItems.size() == 0)
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
            item->setText(0,barejid);
            arbolConectados.addTopLevelItem(item);
            // Refrescamos los items tras la ultima insercion.
            barejidItems = arbolConectados.findItems(barejid,Qt::MatchExactly);
        }

        const auto &firstItem = *barejidItems[0];

        QXmppPresence::Type presenceType = rosterManager.getPresence(barejid,resource).type();
        QIcon onlineIcon;
        onlineIcon.addFile(":/icons/user-online.png");

        switch (presenceType)
        {
            case QXmppPresence::Available:
                QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
                item->setText(0,resource);
                item->setIcon(0,onlineIcon);
                firstItem.addChild(item);
                break;

            case QXmppPresence::Unavailable:
            {
                int i=0;
                //busqueda lineal
                while(i<firstItem.childCount() && firstItem.child(i)->text(0) != resource)
                {
                    i++;
                }
                firstItem.takeChild(i);
                if(barejidItems.childCount() == 0)
                {
                    onlineIcon.addFile(":/icons/user-offline.png");
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        firstItem.setIcon(0,onlineIcon);
    }
}
```

Observarás que además he renombrado la variable `a` para que tenga un nombre más auto-explicativo y he movido algunas variables para que su declaración y su uso esté más próximo, lo cuál también ayuda a razonar sobre el código.

Los dos `if` seguidos que comprueban el valor de `getPresence(barejid,resource).type()` son mútuamente excluyentes (no pueden darse ambos a la vez) así que mejor usar un `switch`.

> ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_static\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 545

No has publicado el código completo, así que no sabremos cuál es la línea 545 de tu código, pero el mensaje claramente indica un acceso a un elemento fuera de rango. Dado que sólo accedes al primer elemento (`[0]`) de la única lista visible en tu código, debe suceder que tu lista está vacía. ¿En qué línea del código que publicaste marca el error? ¿Cuál es el resultado de `ui->arbolConectados->findItems`?